# edit custom javascript to hide nav menu, wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The previous website administrator to this site: http://datingconversation.com has customized the header/logo/nav bar area using jquery. I have been tasked with hiding the nav menu completely and am finding it surprisingly difficult.

Here is the custom javascript code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#menu-item-150").before("<li><a href='/'><img style='margin-right:50px;' src='http://datingconvo.digedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dc_logo_small.png'/></a></li>");
  $("#menu-main").after("<div style='height:50px;width:100%;background-color:white;color:#000880;text-align:center;line-height:50px;font-size:24pt;letter-spacing:1px;font-family:lato,sans-serif;font-weight:300'>Read &bull; Talk &bull; Connect</div>");
});
```

Here is the custom .css code (I know not all of it is relevant but erring on the side of caution):

```css
.cat-bg,
#mgm-header-opacity,
.nav-wrap#nav-clone .mgm-logo,
.nav-wrap#nav-clone .mgm-logo-text,
.sticky .entry-details,
#mgm-full-collapsible .btn-success:hover,
#mgm-full-collapsible .btn-success:focus,
#mgm-full-site-info,
.mgm-cat a,
.mgm-title.mgm-title-skin:after,
.mgm-title a:after,
.mgm-title a:before,
.mgm-title span:after,
.mgm-title span:before,
.inverse .boxed,
.reply-wrap .mgm-reply a,
.article-content-wrapper:hover .img-hover-info,
.rw-criteria.stars-preview,
.rw-bar-progress,
.social-count-plus ul li,
.cat-panes-content .entry-details,
.cat-panes-content .entry-details a,
.rw-user-rating-desc .user_rating,
.rw-user-rating-desc .your_rating,
.mgm-share-text,
.flex-direction-nav,
.woocommerce #comments .star-rating,
.woocommerce-page #comments .star-rating,
.mgm-onsale,
.btn-success,
.btn-success:hover,
.btn-success:active,
.btn-success:focus,
.btn-success.disabled,
.btn-success[disabled],
.generic-button a,
.actions a.mark-read,
div.item-list-tabs ul li a span,
.taxonomy-description p,
.mgm-search-icon-trigger:before,
.mgm-title span.mgm-stripe,
.jackbox-panel:hover,
.woocommerce .widget_price_filter .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle,
.woocommerce-page .widget_price_filter .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle,
.woocommerce-review-link,
.label-minus,
.label-plus,
.single_add_to_cart_button,
.mgm-product-single-wrap .price,
.shop-banner-price .price,
span#subscription-toggle a,
span#favorite-toggle a,
.woocommerce-result-count {
  background-color: #333333!important;
}
.entry-details {
  background-color: #333333!important;
}
.flex-cat {
  background-color: #ffe400!important;
}
.flex-cat a {
  color: #333!important;
}
#masthead {
  display: none;
}
.topnav-wrap {
  display: none;
}
#main {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.main-navigation a {
  color: #ffffff!important;
}
.main-navigation {
  text-align: left;
}
h3 a {
  color: #333333!important;
}
#mgm-toolbar {
  background-color: #666666;
}
#mgm-full-site-info ul li a {
  color: #c1c1c1!important;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.menu-main-container {
  min-width: 997px;
}
#comments {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I'm trying to hide the menu completely without altering the position of the logo. 
Perhaps I could just make the link color the same as the background and somehow prevent the links from being click able...? your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want the logo to stay where it is, but hide the menu? and where is the menu going to be then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to keep the logo but hide the menu links? If so, try something like:

```
ul#menu-main li:nth-child(n+2) { display:none }
```

You could also add `visibility:hidden` to the mix for good measure.

Comment: Thank you, Cynthia. Worked like a charm.